# How can I use methods of a MovieClip that is inside a ScrollPane?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using a `movieClip` inside a `ScrollPane` to show a list of `CheckBoxes`. The amount of `CheckBoxes` shown is dynamic, it depends on a SQL query. After the query is done, I add as many `CheckBoxes` as rows in the result set.

What I am trying to do is to access some methods I wrote in the `MovieClip` inside the `ScrollPane` to get the length of the `CheckBoxes`, check which ones are selected and the label they have (their label is also defined by the SQL query).

I've tried this

```
valueINeedToGet = Object(root).scrollPaneInstance.source.functionINeedToRun();
```

but it returns `error #1006`

Any idea how can I access the code inside the `MovieClip` inside the `ScrollPane`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That error is because you aren't calling your method on a particular instance of your class that extends Movieclip.   Also, making the root an object type will make it into a type that isn't going to implement the function you wrote (obviously) so that call to Object(root) will always fail.

Access the scrollpane by instance name--Then :

Access the children of the Scrollpane, cast them to the class you need them to be, then call the method you need on each one.